# Aharonov-Bohm effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, gauge-invariance

In the build up to Aharonov-Bohm effect, one has to represent the gauge covariant form of STIE. We need to consider two things; the vector potential **A** changes`under gauge transformation and as a consequence, the wavefunction picks up an exponential coefficient to transform to a new wavefunction. 
 $$\vec{A}\longrightarrow\vec{A}+\nabla\chi=\vec{A}' $$
$$\psi \longrightarrow \psi '=e^{\dfrac {ie\chi } {\hbar }}\psi$$
Starting with the TISE for a charged particle in EM field
$$-\dfrac {\hbar ^{2}} {2m}\left( \nabla -\dfrac {ie} {\hbar }\vec{A'}\right) ^{2}\psi' =\left( E-q\phi \right) \psi' ,$$
and assuming that the $\phi$ is time independent. How one can show that by substituting $\vec{A'}$ and $\psi'$ into the given TISE, we will get
$$-\dfrac {\hbar ^{2}} {2m}\left( \nabla -\dfrac {ie} {\hbar }\vec{A}\right) ^{2}\psi =\left( E-q\phi \right) \psi .$$